# rails 3, how to set a user.role in a group#create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a `groups#new` view.  When the current_user is logged in, they are allowed to create a group.

My Groups#new view: the hidden field for the current user works fine, but I need to assign the role = groupleader to this current user.

```
<div>
  <%= fields_for :membership do   %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user_id", current_user.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "role", "groupleader" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Then in my groups#create action:

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group])
  @membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group_id => params[:group_id])
```

This is building a membership but not affecting the role.

My models are as follows:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base #Built with Devise Gem
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships


class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group 
end


class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

---EDIT
Here is what I am playing with.... since I am sending a role parameter through the form,

```
@membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group_id => params[:group_id], :role => params[:role])
```

This is whats going through the log:

```
 Parameters: {"group"=>{"title"=>"Test group w/leader", "description"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Group", "role"=>"groupleader", "authenticity_token"=>"+GCK8bJddObwKdCoiqI5QzlGRyuci8b5JxmgXbOjgsc=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user_id"=>"8"}
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 8 LIMIT 1
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: role
```

Obviously, I have a mass-assign issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your membership model doesn't have attr_accessible for groupleader. Can't this me the reason why is it not working.

Also I suggest naming it as group_leader_id

Comment: membership model just handles the relationship between groups and users/roles.  I can make the role field available via attr_accessible...  I'll play around with that.  How would I name it group_leader_id? groupleader is simply the name of a role.